# Using a function to remove levels from a column in R

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function to remove a certain level in a column in R

```
iris_df <- iris
iris_df$Species2 <- iris_df$Species

purrr::map(.x=c("Species","Species2"),variable="setosa", .f=function(x, variable){
  levels(iris_df[,x])[levels(iris_df[,x]) == variable] <- NA
})
```

I can run this but when I check the levels by doing `levels(iris_df$Species)` the answer is `[1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"`  I would have expected the `setosa` level to have been removed. Can anyone update the code to fix this?

Comment: I have tried `levels(iris_df[,"Species"])[levels(data_list[,"Species"]) == "Setosa"] <- NA` which works, I was just trying to functionise it. I haven't tried `droplevels()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code executed in a function is internal to that function, the global environment is not changed. If you want to write your code like this, with "side effects", you need to use a `for` loop, not inside a function.

```
variable <- "setosa"
for(sp in c("Species","Species2")) {
  levels(iris_df[[sp]])[levels(iris_df[[sp]]) == variable] <- NA
}
```

If you want to use `purrr::map` then you need your function to return something useful, and you need to assign the result with `<-` or `=`. Though it's probably easier to use `dplyr::mutate` when modifying columns of a data frame:

```
## reset the sample data
iris_df <- iris
iris_df$Species2 <- iris_df$Species

variable <- "setosa"
iris_df <- iris_df |>  ## note that we assign the result, so iris_df is modified
  mutate(across(c("Species","Species2"), \(x) {
      levels(x)[levels(x) == variable] <- NA
      x ## the function returns the modified column
    }
  ))
```

If you want to make a more generic "drop level(s) from column(s)" function, then we can wrap either of these approaches into a function, but you will need to pass in the data frame and assign the result to the same data frame or a new data frame:

```
drop_col_levels_for = function(df, cols, levs) {
  for(i in seq_along(cols)) {
    levels(df[[cols[i]]])[levels(df[[cols[i]]]) %in% levs] = NA
  }
  df
}

drop_col_levels_dplyr = function(df, cols, levs) {
  mutate(df, across(all_of(cols), \(x) {
      levels(x)[levels(x) %in% levs] = NA
      x
    }))
}

drop_col_levels_for(iris_df, c("Species","Species2"), "setosa") |>
  summary()
# Sepal.Length    Sepal.Width     Petal.Length    Petal.Width          Species         Species2 
# Min.   :4.300   Min.   :2.000   Min.   :1.000   Min.   :0.100   versicolor:50   versicolor:50  
# 1st Qu.:5.100   1st Qu.:2.800   1st Qu.:1.600   1st Qu.:0.300   virginica :50   virginica :50  
# Median :5.800   Median :3.000   Median :4.350   Median :1.300   NA's      :50   NA's      :50  
# Mean   :5.843   Mean   :3.057   Mean   :3.758   Mean   :1.199                                  
# 3rd Qu.:6.400   3rd Qu.:3.300   3rd Qu.:5.100   3rd Qu.:1.800                                  
# Max.   :7.900   Max.   :4.400   Max.   :6.900   Max.   :2.500     

drop_col_levels_dplyr(iris_df, c("Species","Species2"), "setosa") |>
  summary()
## same result
```

Answer (score 1):

Return the values of columns instead of `levels`.

```
cols <- c("Species","Species2")

iris_df[cols] <- lapply(iris_df[cols], \(x) {
  levels(x)[levels(x) == "setosa"] <- NA
  x
})

levels(iris_df$Species)
#[1] "versicolor" "virginica" 

levels(iris_df$Species2)
#[1] "versicolor" "virginica"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just `replace` with `NA` and use `droplevels()`.

```
> r <- transform(iris, Sp2=droplevels(replace(Species, Species == "setosa", NA)))
> r
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species        Sp2
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa       <NA>
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa       <NA>
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa       <NA>
...
51           7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor versicolor
52           6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor versicolor
...
101          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5  virginica  virginica
102          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9  virginica  virginica
```

where

```
> levels(r$Species2)
[1] "versicolor" "virginica"
```